# multiple datatable on a page with more then 10,000 record loading slow

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have 5 datatable on different tabs on same page, I'm filling them up on page load in same method. I'm using entity framework,database first in mvc

Its loading too slow now. Is there some other way to load them, i was thinking of filling them up from different methods, by calling action method on tab click?

Can someone point me out the correct way to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have to load the 10.000 record at once?

Comment: no..i'm loading 25 at once on each of them. but still my method is loading all of them.. I'm using datatables. M i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample code of what i have done to achieve

jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTable").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/home/LoadData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "ContactName", "name": "ContactName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "CompanyName", "name": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Phone", "name": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Country", "name": "Country", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "City", "name": "City", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "PostalCode", "name": "PostalCode", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
    });
});
```

ASP.NET C# Code (MVC)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadData()
{

    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
    //Find Order Column
    var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();


    int pageSize = length != null? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    int recordsTotal = 0;
    using (MyDatatableEntities dc = new MyDatatableEntities())
    {

        var v = (from a in dc.Customers select a);

        //SORT
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
        {
            v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
        }

        recordsTotal = v.Count();
        var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not essential to load everything at once then:

1. Load only the elements for the active tab
2. Load only a number of elements (for example 10 or 50) and add a pager

This should greatly boost your performance

Comment: can you link me to an example that shows how to do with datatable

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are loading the DataTables?

Comment: i have enabled datatable server side processing. and added code for that. its working great now. thanks for your help